# How to change vue.js directive depending on viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I have an element with the `v-rellax` directive, which is used to enable prallax scrolling in this div:

```
<div id="image" v-rellax="{ speed: -5 }"></div>
```

Now I need to change the `speed` property to `-3` to adapt it to a different `screen width`. Is there a way to change `speed`:

```
1. in a `media query`
2. in `vue.js`
3. in `javascript`
```

Is there a simple way to do that with `vue`?

**Edit:**

I've tried implementing offered solution but the parallax scroll stops working. Have I done it wrong?

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "home",
  data: { rellax_speed: -5 },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
      if (event.target.innerWidth >= 576) {
        this.rellax_speed = -3;
        return;
      }
      this.rellax_speed = -5;
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

template:

```
<div id="image" v-rellax="{ speed: rellax_speed }"></div>
```

**Edit2:**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      r_speed: -5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onresize(event) {
      if (event.target.innerWidth >= 576) {
        this.r_speed = -3;
        return;
      }
      this.r_speed = -5
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onresize)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onresize, true)
  }
}
</script>
```

template:

```
<div id="image" v-rellax="{ speed: r_speed }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I believe to understand you.

**EDIT:**

Thank you tony19 :)

Create vrellaxSpeed in data. Initial value: -5, use it in your directive.

```
data() {
   return { 
      vrellaxSpeed: -5
   }
},
methods:{
   onResize(event) {
      if (event.target.innerWidth > 1280) {
        this.vrellaxSpeed = -3;
        return;
      }
      this.vrellaxSpeed = -5;
   }
},
created() {
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},
beforeDestroy() {
   window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize, true);
}
```

---

Create a **computed** in your vue component.

```
computed: {
   getVrellaxSpeed() {
      return window.innerWidth > 1280 ? -3 : -5;
   }
}
```

Then, use it in your directive prop.

```
<div id="image" v-rellax="{ speed: getVrellaxSpeed }"></div>
```

I did not test it, please try this and give me feedback to help you :)

Comment: @tony19 will the code in **edit** section produce a memory leak?

Comment: https://github.com/croutonn/vue-rellax go to the page and see the destroy heading.

directive parameters is object

Comment: @ÖmerFarukKüçük Your code works but there is one problem. It only works when the viewport width changes, not when you load in a page with a viewport larger than the set pixelwidth. Any way to add this functionality?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Yes, the current edit would still cause a memory leak because of the `true` argument added to the `removeEventListener()` call. There's no corresponding `addEventListener()` with the `true` argument (that flag enables a capturing event listener as opposed to the default bubbling), so the `removeEventListener()` call would not remove anything. The fix is to not pass `true`.